# I tried installing biodigital human, a webgl app on google chrome and it logged me out of my computer and uninstalled some apps

Tags: unity, google-chrome, indicator, webgl

I was logged out. Tried logging in again but waz logged out immediately. Had to reboot. It messed my system up in the following ways:

-Uninstalled wallch and classic menu indicator
-System load indicator is still installed but doesn't show up in the panel. I think its still running, can see it from system monitor
-The network indicator icon is missing from the panel, app is still available in settings.

Using ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS on HP Compaq 6720s with 3GB RAM and Intel Core 2 Duo. I confirmed that I had webgl support before proceeding with the install. please help.

Ok... so i tried reinstalling the uninstalled apps and they both require the removal of google chrome, libindicator1:i368 and libindicator7:i368. Fine with removing(MURDERING) google chrome but dunno bout the other two... going ahead anyway....

Answer (score 1):

Well just uninstalled google chrome and every thing it installed automatically and its all back to normal... No google chrome for me. Na wa...